# Approaches to integrate our Service Desk system with SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, console-application

We have a Service Desk system and using its REST API and on other Scenarios using its Database we need to fetch data from the Service Desk system and populate SharePoint lists. so I am trying to find what is the best way to implement for example this scenario :-

1. Using the Service Desk RESTful API I can get all the new tickets and on other case I can join 5 database tables to get all the new Customer feedbacks' surveys.
2. I need then to populate 2 SharePoint lists; one which contain the Service Desk Tickets and the other list which contain customer feedbacks' surveys.

so I am thinking on this approach:-

1. to write a C# console application (which uses CSOM to integrate with SharePoint) >> which run each 1 hour and this console application will call the Service Desk's RESTful API to check for any new tickets and populate the SharePoint list + the console application will integrate with the database using entity framework and get any new customer feedbacks and populate the SharePoint list .

So is my approach valid? or there is a more appropriate approach to achieve my above requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is valid, but bear in mind that the OOB Microsoft's CSOM library will not work with SharePoint online if the legacy authentication is not allowed. So, instead, it's best to use [**PnP Core** library (deprecated)](https://github.com/PnP/PnP-Sites-Core) or the new cross platform version: [PnP Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework). You can still use CSOM syntax using these libraries. But remember, that with the modern authentication, you will not be able to use login and password. Instead, you will have to rely on App ID and App secret. To get those, you will either need to register SharePoint-only app or an Azure App registration.

**SharePointPnPCoreOnline Nuget Package**

[image]

**Option 1. Granting access using SharePoint App-Only**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

**Option 2. Granting access via Azure AD App-Only**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Comment: i am already using the CSOM code without any issue, where for the authentication i am using this `using (ClientContext context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))` and i have created a APP to work with the CSOM code.. so i am fine?

Comment: Yes! Indeed you are fine. This is exactly what I was talking about. Your entire approach is 100% correct.